# how to Print a curve for each week using the "Close" value in the df dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as dr
df = dr.data.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start = "2019-01-01" , end ="2020-01-13")
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df["Ratio"] = df["Close"] / df["Open"]
df['Day_of_week'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
df['new_col'] = list(zip(df.Date, df.Close, df.Day_of_week))
df.head()
```

`

If the dataset contains 50 week I would like 50 curves, on the y axis the price(close) and for the x axis the days of the week

Comment: Could you try to explain a little more what you mean? It might help if you could draw an example of what you want the graph to look like. (Also you said you want two things to be on the Y axis and didn't mention the X axis)

Comment: I have no idea what your question is asking, as I said, please provide more information, possibly any attempts to code this that you have tried.

Comment: Sure, this is the situation:

My dataset:

Date                 Price        Day_of_week
2020-05-08 9945.05 Friday
2020-05-07       9854.05 Thursday
2020-05-06      9012.00 Wednesday
2020-05-05 9003.07 Tuesday
2020-05-04 8895.75 Monday
2020-05-03 9167.78 Sunday
2020-05-02 8988.60 Saturday
...

I would like to print one curve for each day of the week. where the price in in the Y axis and days of the weeks on X axis. Therefore if in have data for 8 weeks I could see 8 curves in the graph

Comment: So you want a bar chart that looks like in https://benalexkeen.com/bar-charts-in-matplotlib/?

Comment: A line chart where the Y value is Price and de X value is extracted for the column"Day_of_the_week" you can check the data in the first image I provided,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want a standard plot of the price over time. To plot the prices in a line graph can use something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [('2020-05-08', '9945.05', 'Friday'), ('2020-05-07', '9854.05', 'Thursday'),
        ('2020-05-06', '9012.00', 'Wednesday'), ('2020-05-05', '9003.07', 'Tuesday'),
        ('2020-05-04', '8895.75', 'Monday'), ('2020-05-03', '9167.78', 'Sunday'), ('2020-05-02', '8988.60', 'Saturday')]
data.sort(key=lambda d:d[0])
x_pos = list(range(len(data)))
plt.plot(x_pos, [float(d[1]) for d in data])

plt.show()
```

If you want the days of the week to show on the X axis rather than list indices, use the [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [('2020-05-08', '9945.05', 'Friday'), ('2020-05-07', '9854.05', 'Thursday'),
        ('2020-05-06', '9012.00', 'Wednesday'), ('2020-05-05', '9003.07', 'Tuesday'),
        ('2020-05-04', '8895.75', 'Monday'), ('2020-05-03', '9167.78', 'Sunday'), ('2020-05-02', '8988.60', 'Saturday')]
data.sort(key=lambda d:d[0])
x_pos = list(range(len(data)))
plt.plot(x_pos, [float(d[1]) for d in data])

plt.xticks(x_pos, [d[2] for d in data])

plt.show()
```

To use pandas dataframes as described with one curve per week:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as dr

df2 = dr.data.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start="2019-01-01", end="2020-01-13")
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df2['Day_of_week'] = df2['Date'].dt.day_name()
df2['Weekday'] = df2['Date'].dt.weekday #  weekday number

# number week within dataset, 0 for first week, 1 for second week etc.
df2['Week'] = (df2['Date'] - df2['Date'][0]).apply(lambda dt: dt.days // 7)

for week_num, week_df in df2.groupby('Week'):
    if len(week_df['Weekday']) > 7:
        week_df = week_df.drop_duplicates(['Weekday'])
    plt.plot(list(range(len(week_df))), week_df['Close'])

week0_df = next(iter(df2.groupby('Week')))[1]
plt.xticks(list(range(len(week0_df))), week0_df['Day_of_week'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes! your second code looks like what I want. Now inside of data instead of writing manually "('2020-05-08', '9945.05', 'Friday')"  how can I indicate the name of the colums of my dataframe should I use  data = df["Date", "Price", "Day_of_the_week" ]?

Comment: @ricardocalleja can you give some code that produces these dataframes?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df['Day_of_week'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()

#pip install pandas_datareader 

import pandas_datareader as dr
df2 = dr.data.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start = "2019-01-01" , end ="2020-01-13" )
#df2.head(10)
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df2['Day_of_week'] = df2['Date'].dt.day_name()

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Comment: I cannot run that code since I don't know where the `df` variable initially came from. Please include this.

Comment: don't worry the datafarme used is df2. just comment  or delete the line for df

Comment: The value of `df2` is calculated based on `df` because of the line `df2 = dr.data.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start = "2019-01-01" , end ="2020-01-13" )` so this will not work

Comment: `import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as dr
df = dr.data.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start = "2019-01-01" , end ="2020-01-13")
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df["Ratio"] = df2["Close"] / df2["Open"]
df['Day_of_week'] = df2['Date'].dt.day_name()
df['new_col'] = list(zip(df.Date, df.Close, df.Day_of_week))`

Comment: @ricardocalleja I've edited it. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Not quite, because I am trying to plot one curve for each week within the data , and the only values in the X axis should be "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thrusday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday". Your code right now plot only one curve

Comment: @ricardocalleja I have a good feeling about this edit!

Comment: Thanks @Oli, you did it. I really appreciate it